# Apps (client/server) not working with cors when hosted on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, next.js, fetch-api

I am facing an issue when running my apps on the Heroku server; though it was all working fine locally.
I hope some expert or just an second pair of eyes will point something I may be missing.

One app is a server and this is the code:

```
const express = require('express'),
      server = express(),
      cors = require('cors');

server.use(cors({origin: "https://client-fox-67890fghij.herokuapp.com/"}));

server.get('/json-data', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send([
      {order:1,value:2},
      {order:10,value:29}
    ])
});
```

The other app is a client (Next.JS) and this is the code:

The app/page.tsx file:

```
import Receiver from './components/Receiver'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div>
        <Receiver />
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

The app/components/Receiver.tsx file:

```
'use client'

import {useState,useEffect} from "react"
import ListShow from './ListShow'

function Receiver() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  // const apiURL = 'http://localhost:8888/json-data'
  const apiURL = 'https://server-wolf-12345abcde.herokuapp.com/json-data'

  useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;

    async function fetchData() {
      const result = await fetch(apiURL);
      if (!ignore) setData(await result.json());
    }

    fetchData();
    return () => { ignore = true; }
  }, []);

  return <><ListShow dataList={data}/></>;
}


export default Receiver;
```

After uploading both apps and checking that the server side is responding as expected by pointing the web browser to:

```
https://server-wolf-12345abcde.herokuapp.com/json-data
```

When I then point the browser to:

```
https://client-fox-67890fghij.herokuapp.com/
```

I have this error in the Web Developer Tools Console in Firefox:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://server-wolf-12345abcde.herokuapp.com/json-data. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘https://client-fox-67890fghij.herokuapp.com/’).
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

Locally the server ran on localhost:8888 and the client on localhost:3000.

Then in the server I was using:

```
server.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:3000"}));
```

Why is it no longer working when the server and the client are hosted on Heroku ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the exact error message, or did you massage it a bit (e.g. to hide your actual Heroku domains)? No apps appear to be hosted at those URLs, and I wonder if this obscured the problem by subtly changing the domain in the error message.

[The documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuration-options) gives examples for the `origin` without a trailing slash:

> For example if you set it to `"http://example.com"` only requests from “http://example.com” will be allowed.

When `origin` is a string, [comparison is made using `===`](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/f038e7722838fd83935674aa8c5bf452766741fb/lib/index.js#L28) which means it's not going to be very flexible on this point. Playing around in my browser, it looks like requests *don't* include a trailing slash in the `Origin` header.

Try removing that slash:

```
server.use(cors({origin: "https://client-fox-67890fghij.herokuapp.com"}));
//                                                                   ^
```

Comment: Yes I "massaged the message a bit" (forgive my using of your expression) to hide my actual Heroku domains.
I see it as some kind of precaution. I supposed I could post the real URL, if necessary, without compromising too much.
Your comment is appropriate and it works.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, URLs don't match. It is typical for services like Heroku to give different URLs on redeploy as seems to be the case. Working to fix CORS is probably not the best approach for this case. I think you should call an API in your Next app that forwards the call to the other URL. Something like an `app/json-data/route.ts` file with

```
export async function GET() {
  const res = await fetch('https://server-wolf-12345abcde.herokuapp.com/json-data')
  const data = await res.json()
  return Response.json({ data })
}
```

and, in your `Receiver.tsx` change to

```
    async function fetchData() {
      const result = await fetch('/json-data');
      if (!ignore) setData(await result.json());
    }
```

Comment: "It is typical for services like Heroku to give different URLs on redeploy as seems to be the case"—Heroku doesn't do this on redeploy. It _does_ do it if you create a new app, or you can explicitly change it.